# Amazon RDS SQL Server permissions with legacy application

Tags: amazon-web-services, sql-server, amazon-rds, sql-server-2012, aws-directory-service

I am trying to run a legacy Windows application in AWS without modifying the code. The application uses Windows Authentication for the DB connection so this is what I have set up:

1. a Simple Directory Service instance (with "real" AD not the Samba service with 2 domain controllers)
2. a Windows 2012r2 Server EC2 instance joined to the domain: this is where I want to run my app
3. a small RDS SQL Server 2014 Express Edition, also joined to the domain

I have SSMS installed on the EC2 server and I can authenticate to the RDS either using SQL Server Authentication and using the master credentials or using Windows Authentication as the delegated Domain Admin account.

My application has a service user that it uses to connect. I've created a login for that user in the RDS (using SSMS) and given it access to the application database.

When I try to start my application it tries to connect but fails with this error:

> Cannot execute as the database principal because the principal "guest"
>   does not exist, this type of principal cannot be impersonated, or you
>   do not have permission.

In trying to track this down I ran a packet trace with Wireshark. Wireshark can't completely parse all the traffic. I do notice a few things. Firstly that 'use [master]' is sent which (successfully) switches context from the DB I want to use to master. I know my user has minimal access to master and this is limited by RDS -- unless I'm missing a way to give more access. There is a version check then this query:

```
select loginname from dbo.sysusers u, master.dbo.syslogins l 
    where u.name = user and u.sid = l.sid
```

Which appears to get an empty result (confirmation: I get an empty result running this query as the same user in SMSS against master). Then this undocumented stored procedure is executed:

```
exec sp_MSdbuserpriv N'ver'
```

And the response is this failure (as above):

> Cannot execute as the database principal because the principal "guest" does not exist, this type of principal cannot be impersonated, or you do not have permission.

I understand that this is telling me something about permissions but I do not know what to try based on it. As far as I know my user has no business doing stuff in the master db.

**Update**

Reviewing the wireshark capture in more detail shows that an initial connection to the DB works just fine. I can see information is successfully fetched from the DB. It then disconnects, reconnects, switches to the master db and executes the SP mentioned above (which fails yielding the error that I'm seeing). Will update further if I find anything more.

**Update #2**

I'm still plugging away at this but have made no real progress. One thing I have noticed is that the working connection is done via a .Net client of some kind whereas the connection which fails is using DMO.

These are the commands sent by the DMO client before it fails:

```
set quoted_identifier off
SET TEXTSIZE 64512
select @@microsoftversion
SELECT ISNULL(SUSER_SNAME(), SUSER_NAME())
use [master]
if (object_id('master.dbo.sp_MSSQLDMO90_version') is not null)
    exec .dbo.sp_MSSQLDMO90_version
else if (object_id('master.dbo.sp_MSSQLDMO80_version') is not null)
    exec master.dbo.sp_MSSQLDMO80_version
else if (object_id('master.dbo.sp_MSSQLDMO70_version') is not null)
    exec master.dbo.sp_MSSQLDMO70_version
else select 0
select loginname from dbo.sysusers u, master.dbo.syslogins l where u.name = user and u.sid = l.sid<
exec sp_MSdbuserpriv N'ver'
```

All this would work except for the 'user master' line. At this point I'm expecting this might be effectively a mismatch between this application and Amazon's SQL Server RDS offering.

Comment: Could you try to grant your use "Sysadmin" rights, to see if the problem lies in the SQL Server or before it?
Something like ALTER SERVER ROLE sysadmin ADD MEMBER x

Comment: Thanks. I bet this would do it but on RDS I am unable to add users to the sysadmin role. I think at this stage I have two options: beg for a code change, just use a full SQL server instance on ec2.

Comment: on https://www.experts-exchange.com/questions/26417678/sp-MSdbuserpriv.html there is an explanation of what sp_MSdbuserpriv is doing. 
Do you have a "Database=myDataBase;" statement in your connection string?
Maybe you want to ask this question on dba.stackexchange.com where there are people who know RDS?

Comment: Thank you @HenrikStaunPoulsen. I have made no progress getting this to work without code changes. I was able to contact the developers and they've given me a dev build without the problem code (turns out the information it is trying to find is also written to the client registry so this extra check isn't really needed). Anyway, in short, I never found a fix to this.

Comment: For future reference, could you post the code changes from your developers, please?